# VB.NET - ChangeOpacity não funciona

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vb.net

Ao executar meu código a seguinte mensagem me aparece: 
"BC30451 - ChangeOpacity não está declarado. Ele pode estar inacessível devido ao seu nível de proteção."
Estou fazendo um efeito na minha picturebox(static_logo) para que ela desaparece de pouco em pouco.

```
Public Class splashscreenspw
Private Sub Splashscreenspw_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bootsound.URL = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "bootsound" & ".mp3"
    bootsound.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 15 Then
        static_logo.Visible = True
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= 16 Then
        static_logo.Image.Dispose()
        static_logo.Image = ChangeOpacity(My.Resources.bootscreen, 0.3)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 30 Then
        Timer1.Dispose()
        Me.Hide()
        index.ShowDialog()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Class
```

Caso seja útil para visualizar o problema, lá vai uma imagem do meu form:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]